# Using LocationSearchParameter for TargetingIdeaService v201109

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I am trying to use LocationSearchParameter with TargetingIdeaService (v201109). I am struggling with an Invalid_Criterion_ID error. May I request some help with that? Here is how I am setting LocationSearchParameter in php

```
$locationTargetParameter = new LocationSearchParameter(); 
$locationTargetParameter->locations=$LocArray; // $LocArray is array of IDs 2840 for US
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me in case there are others looking to do the same thing:

```
 $loc = array();
 $location = new location();
 $location->id = '2840';
 $loc[]=$location;
 $locationTargetParameter = new LocationSearchParameter();
 $locationTargetParameter->locations=$loc;
```

Comment: The documentation is here: http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/TargetingIdeaService.LocationSearchParameter.html. Posting in case someone wants to know why the above code works.

Answer (score 3):

As of v201702. Here's a working example.

```
$loc = array();
$location = new location();
$location->setId(2840); // USA
$loc[]=$location;
$locationTargetParameter = new LocationSearchParameter();
$locationTargetParameter->setLocations($loc);
$searchParameters[] = $locationTargetParameter;
```

Also if you're copying the example file found [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/php/optimization#get-keyword-ideas). Don't forget to include

`use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201702\o\LocationSearchParameter;`

Since this is needed for the `LocationSearchParameter` to work.

As for documentation and location IDs, check [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201702/TargetingIdeaService.LocationSearchParameter?csw=1).