# Can I search countries by country_code in AdWords API v201603?

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to estimate searches for a keyword, limited to a country.
A similar question was asked about 4 years ago: [Can I search countries by country_code in AdWords API v201109?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887948/using-locationsearchparameter-for-targetingideaservice-v201109/8900799#8900799).

The accepted answer was: it is not currently possible.

We are now at version v201603, and I wonder if there is a change.

In my specific case I code in Java, but will appreciate the answer in any language, I'll be able to find the relevant Java counterpart.

Update:

To add to the accepted answer, here is the list of the country codes extracted from AdWords CSV file.

```
private static HashMap<String, Long> COUNTRIES = new HashMap<String, Long>() {
    {
        put("ad",2020L); //,Andorra
        put("ae",2784L); //,United Arab Emirates
        put("af",2004L); //,Afghanistan
        put("ag",2028L); //,Antigua and Barbuda
        put("al",2008L); //,Albania
        put("am",2051L); //,Armenia
        put("ao",2024L); //,Angola
        put("aq",2010L); //,Antarctica
        put("ar",2032L); //,Argentina
        put("as",2016L); //,American Samoa
        put("at",2040L); //,Austria
        put("au",2036L); //,Australia
        put("az",2031L); //,Azerbaijan
        put("ba",2070L); //,Bosnia and Herzegovina
        put("bb",2052L); //,Barbados
        put("bd",2050L); //,Bangladesh
        put("be",2056L); //,Belgium
        put("bf",2854L); //,Burkina Faso
        put("bg",2100L); //,Bulgaria
        put("bh",2048L); //,Bahrain
        put("bi",2108L); //,Burundi
        put("bj",2204L); //,Benin
        put("bn",2096L); //,Brunei
        put("bo",2068L); //,Bolivia
        put("br",2076L); //,Brazil
        put("bs",2044L); //,The Bahamas
        put("bt",2064L); //,Bhutan
        put("bw",2072L); //,Botswana
        put("by",2112L); //,Belarus
        put("bz",2084L); //,Belize
        put("ca",2124L); //,Canada
        put("cc",2166L); //,Cocos (Keeling) Islands
        put("cd",2180L); //,Democratic Republic of the Congo
        put("cf",2140L); //,Central African Republic
        put("cg",2178L); //,Republic of the Congo
        put("ch",2756L); //,Switzerland
        put("ci",2384L); //,Cote d'Ivoire
        put("ck",2184L); //,Cook Islands
        put("cl",2152L); //,Chile
        put("cm",2120L); //,Cameroon
        put("cn",2156L); //,China
        put("co",2170L); //,Colombia
        put("cr",2188L); //,Costa Rica
        put("cv",2132L); //,Cape Verde
        put("cx",2162L); //,Christmas Island
        put("cy",2196L); //,Cyprus
        put("cz",2203L); //,Czech Republic
        put("de",2276L); //,Germany
        put("dj",2262L); //,Djibouti
        put("dk",2208L); //,Denmark
        put("dm",2212L); //,Dominica
        put("do",2214L); //,Dominican Republic
        put("dz",2012L); //,Algeria
        put("ec",2218L); //,Ecuador
        put("ee",2233L); //,Estonia
        put("eg",2818L); //,Egypt
        put("er",2232L); //,Eritrea
        put("es",2724L); //,Spain
        put("et",2231L); //,Ethiopia
        put("fi",2246L); //,Finland
        put("fj",2242L); //,Fiji
        put("fm",2583L); //,Federated States of Micronesia
        put("fr",2250L); //,France
        put("ga",2266L); //,Gabon
        put("gb",2826L); //,United Kingdom
        put("gd",2308L); //,Grenada
        put("ge",2268L); //,Georgia
        put("gh",2288L); //,Ghana
        put("gm",2270L); //,The Gambia
        put("gn",2324L); //,Guinea
        put("gq",2226L); //,Equatorial Guinea
        put("gr",2300L); //,Greece
        put("gs",2239L); //,South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands
        put("gt",2320L); //,Guatemala
        put("gu",2316L); //,Guam
        put("gw",2624L); //,Guinea-Bissau
        put("gy",2328L); //,Guyana
        put("hm",2334L); //,Heard Island and McDonald Islands
        put("hn",2340L); //,Honduras
        put("hr",2191L); //,Croatia
        put("ht",2332L); //,Haiti
        put("hu",2348L); //,Hungary
        put("id",2360L); //,Indonesia
        put("ie",2372L); //,Ireland
        put("il",2376L); //,Israel
        put("in",2356L); //,India
        put("iq",2368L); //,Iraq
        put("is",2352L); //,Iceland
        put("it",2380L); //,Italy
        put("jm",2388L); //,Jamaica
        put("jo",2400L); //,Jordan
        put("jp",2392L); //,Japan
        put("ke",2404L); //,Kenya
        put("kg",2417L); //,Kyrgyzstan
        put("kh",2116L); //,Cambodia
        put("ki",2296L); //,Kiribati
        put("km",2174L); //,Comoros
        put("kn",2659L); //,Saint Kitts and Nevis
        put("kr",2410L); //,South Korea
        put("kw",2414L); //,Kuwait
        put("kz",2398L); //,Kazakhstan
        put("la",2418L); //,Laos
        put("lb",2422L); //,Lebanon
        put("lc",2662L); //,Saint Lucia
        put("li",2438L); //,Liechtenstein
        put("lk",2144L); //,Sri Lanka
        put("lr",2430L); //,Liberia
        put("ls",2426L); //,Lesotho
        put("lt",2440L); //,Lithuania
        put("lu",2442L); //,Luxembourg
        put("lv",2428L); //,Latvia
        put("ly",2434L); //,Libya
        put("ma",2504L); //,Morocco
        put("mc",2492L); //,Monaco
        put("md",2498L); //,Moldova
        put("me",2499L); //,Montenegro
        put("mg",2450L); //,Madagascar
        put("mh",2584L); //,Marshall Islands
        put("mk",2807L); //,Macedonia (fyroM)
        put("ml",2466L); //,Mali
        put("mn",2496L); //,Mongolia
        put("mp",2580L); //,Northern Mariana Islands
        put("mr",2478L); //,Mauritania
        put("mt",2470L); //,Malta
        put("mu",2480L); //,Mauritius
        put("mv",2462L); //,Maldives
        put("mw",2454L); //,Malawi
        put("mx",2484L); //,Mexico
        put("my",2458L); //,Malaysia
        put("mz",2508L); //,Mozambique
        put("na",2516L); //,Namibia
        put("nc",2540L); //,New Caledonia
        put("ne",2562L); //,Niger
        put("nf",2574L); //,Norfolk Island
        put("ng",2566L); //,Nigeria
        put("ni",2558L); //,Nicaragua
        put("nl",2528L); //,Netherlands
        put("no",2578L); //,Norway
        put("np",2524L); //,Nepal
        put("nr",2520L); //,Nauru
        put("nu",2570L); //,Niue
        put("nz",2554L); //,New Zealand
        put("om",2512L); //,Oman
        put("pa",2591L); //,Panama
        put("pe",2604L); //,Peru
        put("pf",2258L); //,French Polynesia
        put("pg",2598L); //,Papua New Guinea
        put("ph",2608L); //,Philippines
        put("pk",2586L); //,Pakistan
        put("pl",2616L); //,Poland
        put("pm",2666L); //,Saint Pierre and Miquelon
        put("pn",2612L); //,Pitcairn Islands
        put("pt",2620L); //,Portugal
        put("pw",2585L); //,Palau
        put("py",2600L); //,Paraguay
        put("qa",2634L); //,Qatar
        put("ro",2642L); //,Romania
        put("rs",2688L); //,Serbia
        put("ru",2643L); //,Russia
        put("rw",2646L); //,Rwanda
        put("sa",2682L); //,Saudi Arabia
        put("sb",2090L); //,Solomon Islands
        put("sc",2690L); //,Seychelles
        put("se",2752L); //,Sweden
        put("sg",2702L); //,Singapore
        put("sh",2654L); //,Saint Helena
        put("si",2705L); //,Slovenia
        put("sk",2703L); //,Slovakia
        put("sl",2694L); //,Sierra Leone
        put("sm",2674L); //,San Marino
        put("sn",2686L); //,Senegal
        put("so",2706L); //,Somalia
        put("sr",2740L); //,Suriname
        put("st",2678L); //,Sao Tome and Principe
        put("sv",2222L); //,El Salvador
        put("sz",2748L); //,Swaziland
        put("td",2148L); //,Chad
        put("tf",2260L); //,French Southern and Antarctic Lands
        put("tg",2768L); //,Togo
        put("th",2764L); //,Thailand
        put("tj",2762L); //,Tajikistan
        put("tk",2772L); //,Tokelau
        put("tl",2626L); //,Timor-Leste
        put("tm",2795L); //,Turkmenistan
        put("tn",2788L); //,Tunisia
        put("to",2776L); //,Tonga
        put("tr",2792L); //,Turkey
        put("tt",2780L); //,Trinidad and Tobago
        put("tv",2798L); //,Tuvalu
        put("tz",2834L); //,Tanzania
        put("ua",2804L); //,Ukraine
        put("ug",2800L); //,Uganda
        put("um",2581L); //,United States Minor Outlying Islands
        put("us",2840L); //,United States
        put("uy",2858L); //,Uruguay
        put("uz",2860L); //,Uzbekistan
        put("va",2336L); //,Vatican City
        put("vc",2670L); //,Saint Vincent and the Grenadines
        put("ve",2862L); //,Venezuela
        put("vn",2704L); //,Vietnam
        put("vu",2548L); //,Vanuatu
        put("wf",2876L); //,Wallis and Futuna
        put("ws",2882L); //,Samoa
        put("ye",2887L); //,Yemen
        put("za",2710L); //,South Africa
        put("zm",2894L); //,Zambia
        put("zw",2716L); //,Zimbabwe

    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Stewart. Articles in English are notoriously hard for the native Russian speakers :)

Comment: My pleasure. You certainly made it much clearer than I would have managed in Russian! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can use the Targeting Idea Service to specify any location code (which includes countries, regions, cities, etc) for a Search Volume based query.

I am unfamiliar with the Java client library but I am sure it will be similar to the .NET one. The C# code below outputs the search volume for the terms 'blue fedora' and 'red fedora' for queries based in Canada.

```cs
var targettingIdeaSvc = (TargetingIdeaService)awUser.GetService(AdWordsService.v201601.TargetingIdeaService);
var searchQueries = new string[] { "blue fedora", "red fedora" };

var ideasPg = targettingIdeaSvc.get(new TargetingIdeaSelector
{
    ideaType = IdeaType.KEYWORD,
    requestType = RequestType.STATS,
    requestedAttributeTypes = new AttributeType[]
    {
        AttributeType.SEARCH_VOLUME
    },
    searchParameters = new SearchParameter[]
    {
        new RelatedToQuerySearchParameter
        {
            queries = searchQueries,
        },
        new LocationSearchParameter
        {
            locations = new Location[]
            {
                new Location
                {
                    id = 2124 // This is the location id for Canada - comprehensive list of location ids is available here https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting
                }
            }
        },
    },
    paging = new Paging
    {
        numberResults = 5,
        startIndex = 0
    }
});
for (var i = 0; i < searchQueries.Length; i++)
{
    var searchVolume = (ideasPg.entries[i].data.First().value as LongAttribute).value;
    Console.WriteLine($@"Search Term: ""{searchQueries[i]}"" has search volume of {searchVolume} in Canada");
}
```

This service uses a location id. You can look up a specific id from the [AdWords Geo-Location reference page](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting) (or even access this list programatically if you need to)

Comment: Yes, I believe it to be the correct answer. I  have done something like this too. One thing that is missing, is where to get the list of the country codes. I will add the list to my question